# Nginx shows started in terminal but could not be accessed in browser(Mac OS)

Tags: macos, nginx

```
$ brew services list

...
nginx             started root    /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.nginx.plist
...
```

I have installed nginx using brew and started the nginx server using `sudo brew services start nginx`, I checked the error logs, there is no errors displayed, I changed the listen port to 6666.

But the default nginx page is not showing up in browser, what could be wrong?

#### Update

**Terminal**

[image]

**Firewall**
[image]

**Chrome**
[image]

Comment: What URL are you using in the browser, and what error or result are you getting? Also, are you sure `nginx` is listening as expected? Run `netstat -an | grep '[.]6666` and see what that shows.

Comment: @GordonDavisson TCP4/ TCP6 *.6666 LISTEN

Comment: I am using the`http://localhost:6666/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you setup nginx correctly but the browser does not allow you to see the 6666 port for security reasons. If you are using Chrome, you have to quit it (be sure to quit fully with File menu > Quit or Command-Q, don't just close all windows) and then re-open it using the terminal with a specific parameter to allow 6666 port.

```
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666
```

If that doesn't work check your MacOSX Firewall in "System Preferences" - "Security" - "Firewall", also check if you have an antivirus blocking the connection.

I didn't have to use "sudo" to start the nginx server, only "brew services start nginx"

Comment: Firewall is off and the command sees not working, :(

Comment: @minglyu, what do you see in the terminal when you type "open -a "Google Chrome" --args --explicitly-allowed-ports=6666" ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it just jump to the chrome and doesn't show anything

Comment: @minglyu The "ERR_UNSAFE_PORT" message in your screenshot sure makes it look like this is the problem. Did you quit Chrome before running the `open ...` command? It won't work if Chrome is already running.

Comment: Wow, it worked! thank you very much! why chrome block 6666?

Comment: @minglyu It's to keep your browser from being used for a [NAT bypass attack](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/new-slipstream-nat-bypass-attacks-to-be-blocked-by-browsers/). See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-unsafe-by-chrome) for a list of blocked ports.